# I guess I need a static IP, right?

Tags: static, ip, moodle

I work at the school where we have our internet distributed through three APs (it's a small school). I have connected one computer to the switch as my Moodle server. Assigned IP for that computer is, of course, 192.168.... Now. I'd like to access my Moodle from outside our network.

I'm not sure if I need a static IP for this or a reserved address with port forwarding?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a static ip. just configure a dynamic dns (like no-ip or dyndns) and point the external ports 80 (HTTP) and 443 (HTTPS) of your router to the ip address of the Moodle Server.